# What is the difference between PivotTable.RefreshTable and PivotTable.Update?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

What is the difference between the methods `pivottable.refreshtable` and `pivottable.update`?

I have been googleling and haven't figured out if `pivottable.refreshtable` is enough to update a pivottable or if `pivottable.update` also does something significant.

Comment: is it about MS excel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Update` merely updates the layout - it doesn't refresh the data.

Comment: Simple and best explanation :)

Comment: Ok, so if I use .RefreshTable, I don't need to use .Update as well?

Comment: No. You only really need to use `Update` if you've set the `ManualUpdate` property of the pivot table to True and want to update the table for some reason before making `ManualUpdate` False again.